# locale-gen with purge does not work

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, localization

I use the `--purge` option to remove existing locales before generating new one, but seems cannot remove existing locales?

e.g.

```
# locale-gen --purge en_US
# locale -a
C
en_AG
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_US
en_US.utf8
POSIX
zh_TW
```

Comment: What distribution do you use?

Comment: @Sacx Since he tagged it Ubuntu, I would assume that is th edistro he's using.

Answer (score 10):

1. Clean /usr/lib/locale/ (delete everything, do a backup if you are afraid).
2. Delete unneeded locale from /etc/default/locale file (do not delete this file, edit and delete the locales)
3. Delete unneeded locale from /var/lib/locales/supported.d/* files (do not delete this files, edit them and delete the locales)
4. Regenerate locales (locale-gen --purge).

Also you can try localepurge as Juice sad earlier.

Comment: It also works if instead of #4 you execute `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo edit /etc/default/locale
```

Edit the `LANGUAGE` variable to remove `whatever language that needs removed`. Then `reboot`.

```
sudo apt-get install localepurge
```

After that you can run `localepurge` to remove old locale files.

Answer (score 1):

Sure? you have run it as `root` or using `sudo`:

```
sudo locale-gen --purge en_US
```

Because it doesn't raise any error if you run it as regular user

Answer (score -1):

Just do the following command if it is Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y language-pack-en-base
```